# are the uses of 'bare infinitive' & 'participle' same here?

Tags: sentence-meaning, present-participles, bare-infinitives

- > I saw him **sing**
- > I saw him **singing**

In the first example, the verb *sing* is used as a bare infinitive and in the following one it is exemplified as a present participle. My question is  if both of them are expressing the same meaning?

Answer (score 1):

As with many parts of English, they *mean* the same, but have different connotation.

**I saw him sing** gives it less weight, maybe you saw someone singing in the street and walked by or saw someone sing to themselves while doing housework.

**I saw him singing** make is sound like it caught your attention a little better.  Maybe you saw someone singing in the street, and you stopped to watch.

By using *singing* it feel like the emphasis is on the singing, whereas *saw him sing* puts the emphasis on you and what you saw.

Again, both could easily be used for either, I can't think of a situation where one would work but not the other.

And as always in English, other versions of English may feel differently.  I'm from Northern California.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the infinitive you stress the fact. If you use the present participle you stress the ongoing action, which is comparable to a close-up in a film.