# "Went" or "go" in "I saw Kyoko went/go out of city hall."

Tags: tense, infinitives

> I saw Kyoko went out of city hall.
>   I saw Kyoko go out of city hall.

I thought 'went' is the correct answer 
Why it has to be 'go'?
Can anyone explain this to me

Comment: *Personally*, I wouldn't use either. They both sound bad. "Exit" or "leave" would be much better than "went/go out".

Comment: I agree with Catija, though I'll add that if you were outside "*come* out" would be fine.

Comment: Yeah i think exit/leave is better but if i choose the option 'went' is it grammatically incorrect?

Comment: If you say "I saw Kyoko go out the city hall door", that is more typically idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the action happened in the past, you don't use *went*. *See* is a [verb of perception](http://www.englishgrammar.org/verbs-perception/) and in this case it should be *object + bare infinitive*: I saw Kyoko go out of city hall. This means that Kyoko left city hall and you saw it.

However, *go out of city hall* sounds strange to me. Perhaps with more context it might sound better, but I agree with the comments. I think you should use a different verb like *leave*, *exit*, *come out*, *walk out*, etc.

Comment: Ah i see, its verb of preposition so it has to be bare infinitive. Thankyou so much for explaining to me grammatically!! Though, 'go out' is not too fit in this context and i agree leave/exit is better

Comment: @Max: Can't we use present participle after a verb of perception such as see? I saw he Kyoko *going* out of city hall.

Comment: @user3257464 Yes, it's possible (I think you mean "I saw Kyoko going out of city hall"), but the question didn't ask about that. I think the distinction is that the bare infinitive implies you saw the entire action.

Comment: @Max: Yes, the question has not. That was a mistake. I meant what you meant. OK. I will ask that question if it has not been asked before.

Comment: @user3257464 It has probably been asked before. Try [searching first](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=present+participle+infinitive), and if you are not satisfied, then ask.

Comment: @Max: Found it: (https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/60078/are-the-uses-of-bare-infinitive-participle-same-here)